# Set background image in storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

Can i set the background image from storyboard? 
I've set background in code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png"))
}
```

Comment: If adding a `UIImageView` and setting its image is fine with you than yes, you can. Otherwise I don't think you can do this on the default `UIView`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Simple:

Add `UIImageView` to your Storyboard to the **most bottom** of your view hierarchy.

.

.
[image]

Comment: Or, you can just do `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png"))` in `viewDidLoad`. Screw a storyboard.